# Adding commas in inputs in Python?

Tags: python

I want to make this program in Python 3.3.2 which asks you for the radius and height of a cylinder which you have to type in as `radius`, `height`
Here is the current code:

```
if response=="vol":
    radius = float(input("What is the radius and height of the cylinder? (e.g. 32, 15): "))
```

How should I change it?
After that I will calculate its volume: V = hπr<sup>2</sup>
How will I do this with your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
radius, height = [float(part) for part in input("What is the radius and height of the cylinder? (e.g. 32, 15): ").split(',')]
```

The `split` splits the input at the comma into two parts; the `for` is part of a list comprehension, which creates a list by applying the same action to each result.

Comment: @JasonSperske, yes it would, but Guido prefers list comprehensions and I'm not going to argue with him.

Comment: Is the con readability or some shortsightedness in the `map()` function?

Comment: Hi I don't get this part of the code: [float(part) for part in input

Comment: @TimTimmy, look at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. Instead of using a `range` as in the example, I'm using the results of `split` which returns strings in a list.

Comment: I've been working my way through The Little Schemer so this in really fascinating to me.  Thanks for the link :)